# Add text inside the DIV on top image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add text "Post" in the center of Div on top of image , but it adds next to the image:

HTML:

```
<div id="Post">
    <span  class="Post">Post
        <img src="images/ask_post.png" />
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Post {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('../images/ask_post.png') no-repeat;
    left:741px;
    top:157px;
}
```

Comment: Use no-repeat in background-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the image from the div element, the text wont go on top of that image, only the background. Second, play around with the [background properties](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_background.asp) until it looks like you want it to.

My guess is that you need to adjust the [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) or [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_background-position.asp).

```
<div id="Post">
    <span  class="Post">Post</span>
</span>
```

See if `background-size:cover;` is what you need. You'll probably also have to adjust the `height` and `width` of the div to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the image twice.  Once in the css and again in the div.  Remove